# How to identify capturing groups in a string

Tags: c#

```
dst = "$3$1$2_BAR.xml";
```

How would i identify capturing groups in a string easily?  So for the above I want to identify that I'm looking for 3 capturing groups which I will then pull from another string and insert in here accordingly.  so scanning the string should I be looking for '$' followed by a digit? any problems with that? anyone see any better ways?

what I'm trying to do is automate a process of renaming a file.  dst tells me what the new file must look like, these capturing groups come from a source file that is curretly named

```
src = 08_21_2013_foo.xml
```

for ex.  the capturing groups are captured according to a file pattern

```
src_pattern = "(\d\d)_(\d\d)_(\d\d\d\d)_FOO.xml";
```

so I'd need to pull the 3rd group which is '2013' followed by the 1st which is '08 then the 2nd which is '21' so looks like `20130821_BAR.xml` when done.

With a single file and all these things provided to the user it's not hard, but dst and src_pattern are being pulled from sql server and the user has no idea what they look like, it could be

`$3_insert_$1_randomly_$2_in_$5_here_$4.xml` to give an example.

so basically I need a way to scan the dst string, sees the $3 and goes into src and pulls the third group and replace it, then sees the $2 and goes into src and pull it and replace with it, etc... I don't know if I explained it well enough.

do not restrict it to this specific example it needs to work for any dst, I'm not interested in what dst looks, nothing is hardcoded.  Think of this as a search and replace but with capturing groups

Comment: I don't understand what you're looking for? What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Are you trying to reinvent regular expressions?

Comment: why downvote...how is this question not useful or show no effort...

Answer (score 1):

You can easily use String.Format to construct your string. The following example should give you a hint

```
string one ="first";
string two = " second";
string three = "third";

string result = String.Format("{0}{1}{2}_BAR.xml",three,one,two);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to go out on a limb and answer the question I think you're asking. It sounds like you're asking how to parse a delimited string.

Try string.split

```
string[] values = dst.split('$')
```

**EDIT:**

So now that you've updated your question I think I'm a little closer to understanding your question but it's still a little nebulous. Now it sounds like you're trying to replace some placeholder values `$n` with values pulled from another string somehow. Do you have a way to pull the groups from src_patter?

Here's what I would do, though there may be more efficient ways.

```
string[] group = new string[] { "08", "21", "2013" }; /* group from src_pattern */
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("$3$1$2_BAR.xml");
for (int i = 1; i <= group.Length; i++)
{
    sb.Replace("$" + i.ToString(), group[i - 1]);
}
Console.WriteLine(sb.ToString());
```

Comment: I think you get what I mean but just splitting by delimiter wouldn't get me too far, I need to way to extract all the $k where k is an integer

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to split the thing out, and then do a replace...

if you have

```
$3_insert_$1_randomly_$2_in_$5_here_$4.xml
```

Then you will know how many $X you will have to replace.

Giving that X will give you the number in the original string that you have, you can do a Split on the source string (based on _) and then just for a replace pattern, until you do not find any more replacements objects..